# How to pass parameters through url in angular

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am trying to pass parameters through URL using in angular Http Post method but I am getting unknown exception i.e **Http failure response for (unknown URL): 0 Unknown Error** but its working fine in Postman client. Where I did a mistake? below I am sharing stackbliz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client-1donxb?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Is not recommend to add user credential in url so I modify your code a little bit like this

```
  apiUrl = 'http://192.168.82.51:8080/touch-crm/users/signin';

  GetData() {
      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        })
      };

      let body = {
        username: "admin",
        password: "admin"
      }

      return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, body, httpOptions).subscribe((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
      });      
  }
```

Comment: i am getting same error did you check this in stackbliz?

Comment: Yes but your api url is not accesable

Comment: oh ok but getting same error Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

Comment: Can you still access the api ?

Comment: Then you should config the CORS in the API side. My code will work

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're trying to access a resource that uses http while stackblitz uses https. Browsers block loading http content from a https page.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content for an explanation.
You can see this error if you open the developer console in firefox or chrome (f12 or ctrl+shift+i) and then press the load data button again.

There isn't an easy way to fix this, apart from using a https api. You could set up https://ngrok.com/ to get a secure connection to your local api, or serve angular locally https://cli.angular.io/ on http.

Tony Ngo is right about passing the parameters in the body, it's a lot cleaner to pass them as an object.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any backend or file defined to handle this url?
Not able to check in your stackbliz link since your IP is there and call is getting failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
try to do like this.

routing path
    > {path: 'devicelog/:id/:device', component: DevicelogComponent}

    DevicelogComponent
    > this.router.navigate(['campaigns', name]);

    campaigns component

    >   this.route.params
        .subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
        this.campId = params.name;
        if (params) {
        this.campName = params.name;
        if (this.campName) {
        this.singleCampaigns();
        }
        } else {
        this.campName = 'Sorry';
        }
        }
        );
```